# How to set limit rows for each page in jasper report?

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

Jasper Version : 6.0.1

i wonder did version of jasper was changed every keyword ?

i use this code on break page last year it work.

```
$V{COLUMN_NUMBER} == 6
```

but now stop working.

example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.0  -->
<!-- 2015-11-06T11:20:46 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report8" language="groovy" columnCount="5" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="995" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="138" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5e2835cc-bc36-4f77-8631-08a8deaa28d7">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="spaTd"/>
    <queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
    collectionName: 'branch',
    findFields: { _id:1, code:1, name:1 }
}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="76707cdd-7dbe-477e-b3a4-38f9ba3bd003"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="19" width="100" height="1" uuid="4f383cfa-5b99-465d-9a35-ca598aed7a6f">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} == 6]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20" uuid="294bf799-580b-450e-9a04-a4c2f83ba296"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

***i still confuse why number 6 of column not move with another page ?

[image]

Comment: i don't, it just test, like as i drawed, i just want when column reach to 5, another column should be go to another page

Comment: I added you an answer how to achive this with group... and printOrder="Horizontal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! it working now!!!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.0  -->
<!-- 2015-11-13T10:43:56 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report8" language="groovy" columnCount="5" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="995" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="138" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5e2835cc-bc36-4f77-8631-08a8deaa28d7">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="spaTd"/>
    <queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
    collectionName: 'branch',
    findFields: { _id:1, code:1, name:1 }
}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="ReportCount" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{COLUMN_COUNT}<6)]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="2"/>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="76707cdd-7dbe-477e-b3a4-38f9ba3bd003"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20" uuid="294bf799-580b-450e-9a04-a4c2f83ba296"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the print order on your jasperReport `printOrder="Horizontal"`  for the `<break>` command to work correctly you need to have `printOrder="Vertical"`

However if I would like to have a page break after column 6 with `printOrder="Horizontal"` I would use group and do something like this.

```
<group name="ReportCount" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}<=6)]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="2"></band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

Hence as $V{REPORT_COUNT} > 6 it switches from true -- > false, executing the new group that `isStartNewPage="true"`

Comment: thank you!, i have refer from your code, and now i manipulated it works like i want!!